# removing header and keep footer on the left from even empty pages at the end of chapters

Tags: header-footer

I would like to remove the header, but not the footer (page number) from the empty page at the end of chapters in my thesis. I used:

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,openright,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[width=170.00mm, height=240.00mm, left=2.0cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.2 cm, bottom=1.80cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %necessary to set your own header and footer style
\pagestyle{fancy} %necessary to set your own header and footer style
\fancyhf{} %clear the header and the footer before you define your own
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage} %footer in odd pages on the right
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage} %footer in even pages on the left

\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\vspace{\fill}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

some text here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to produce a header on those pages, just a footer with a centered page number.

Comment: Yes indeed, but I would like to have the numbers on the left on those even empty pages that are added at the end of chapter.

Comment: Do you want the page numbers on the right for the start-of-chapter pages as well?

Comment: I/m actually OK with the page numbers in the center of the start-of-chapter pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the redefinition of `\cleardoublepage` you set the pagestyle of those pages to `plain`, which is the same as the pagestyle for the first page of a chapter. In the below code I make a new pagestyle, and use that in the redefinition of `\cleardoublepage`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,openright,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[width=170.00mm, height=240.00mm, left=2.0cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.2 cm, bottom=1.80cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %necessary to set your own header and footer style
\pagestyle{fancy} %necessary to set your own header and footer style
\fancyhf{} %clear the header and the footer before you define your own
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage} %footer in odd pages on the right
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage} %footer in even pages on the left

\fancypagestyle{endofchapter}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\vspace{\fill}
\thispagestyle{endofchapter}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @Elisa No worries. Remember that you can mark questions as solved by accepting an answer (clicking the checkmark to the left of an answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can patch `emptypage` to use a different page style than `empty`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,openright,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
  width=170.00mm,
  height=240.00mm,
  left=2.0cm,
  right=2.00cm,
  top=2.2cm,
  bottom=1.80cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{emptypage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %necessary to set your own header and footer style
\pagestyle{fancy} %necessary to set your own header and footer style
\fancyhf{} %clear the header and the footer before you define your own
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage} %footer in odd pages on the right
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage} %footer in even pages on the left
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}

\fancypagestyle{almostempty}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}% footer in even pages on the left
}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\emptypage@emptypage}{empty}{almostempty}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{One}

Some text to have a page

\chapter{Two}
\section{Section title}

Some text to have a page

\newpage

And another one to see the header and footer

\newpage

And another one to see the header and footer

\end{document}
```

If you'd like the page number in the otherwise empty page is centered, just remove the code for the `almostempty` page style and replace `almostempty` with `plain` in the code of `\patchcmd`.

[image]